# php include .php and .html file from different directory dont load css and js

Tags: php

i have folders like this

```
\htdocs\router\index.php -> main index file
\htdocs\router\view\ -> all html and php files 
\htdocs\router\view\asset -> all css, js , etc files
\htdocs\router\controller\App\main.php -> controller file
```

Now when someone point to http://localhost, the index.php create new object (`new main()` ) from main.php (class main) and executes index function (`public function index() { ... }`) . This function have does an include like this ( `require 'view/login.php';` ).

I can see the output of login.php but all .css, .jpg, .js files wont load because they are declared in login.php like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheed" href="asset/style.css" type="text/css">
```

because the `asset/` directory is located where `login.php` file is.

if i put `href="view/asset/style.css"` it's working .

The question is :

How can i include a .php file from other folder to make it work without chaning the `href` tag and without moving the asset folder up.

Comment: Refer to your assets from the root, rather than using relative paths. You can't go wrong when you do it that way.

Comment: i know but the `asset` folder and `login.php` are both in `view` directory

Comment: If you can't/won't edit the login.php file there's nothing you can do. Well, there's things you could do but they're so convoluted they make very little sense to do.

Comment: Your index.php should be in the view folder, in that case. It's a view, is it not? All your view files should be in there.

Comment: How does your url look like when you visit login.php?

Comment: @RobBiermann `http://localhost/login` ... and if i watch source code of file the  css is at `http://localhost/asset/style.css` but shoud be `http://localhost/view/asset/style.css` . It is because of the include which bring the content of login php from view directory to root base directory and so skipping the view/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't make it work without changing `href` as assets refer to the root, not in the path.

What you can do is make a symlink of `view/asset` to root, So it will assets will be accessible from both `href="asset/style.css"` and `href="view/asset/style.css"`.

Using PHP:

```
symlink("view/asset","asset"); //index.php
```

Or Terminal:

```
ln -s view/asset asset
```

Comment: This is what i want to achieve. to just let `asset/style.css` in there and somehow make a link or something

Comment: use php build-in `symlink()` to create a symlink `view/asset` to root `asset`. `symlink("view/asset","asset");` OR from command line `ln -s view/asset asset`

Comment: This is something what you want?

Comment: i am trying now .. sorry for delay

Comment: Glad it helps you.